# Reference CommonServiceLocator Nuget on .NET Standard 1.4

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, portable-class-library, .net-standard, common-service-locator

Is there an easy way to install the CommonServiceLocator nuget package to a .NET Standard 1.4 project in visual studio 2017?

Installing the nuget package fails with:

> Package CommonServiceLocator 1.3.0 is not compatible with
>   netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Package
>   CommonServiceLocator 1.3.0 supports: portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81
>   (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile328) One or more packages
>   are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.

Comment: The general consensus is that you shouldn't use CommonServiceLocator or any abstraction over DI containres at all. Read [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet packages that are compatible with a PCL can usually be used by using the [`PackageTargetFallback` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#packagetargetfallback) in the csproj file like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that in .NET Standard 2.0 / .NET Core 2.0 tooling, this is changing to `AssetTargetFallback` but should no longer be necessary since .NET Standard and .NET Core 2.0 are automatically compatible with packages that work on .NET 4.6.1.